# Java schoolwork suggestions for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Here I have a school tutorial work which is not an assignment.

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Coin {

private boolean coinSide;
String headSide = "heads";
String tailSide = "tails";

Coin()
{
    coinSide = true;
}

    
public boolean getCoinside()
{
    return coinSide;
}

public int coinToss()
{
    int num = (int)(Math.random() *2); //returns an integer 
    return num;
}
}
```

And next will be my TestCoin.java codings:

```
class TestCoin {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Coin firstCoin = new Coin();
    
    int[] tosses = new int[100];
    int h = 0;
    int t = 0;
    
    for(int counter = 0; counter != tosses.length; counter++)
    {
        if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tosses[counter] = 0;
            t++;
        } else if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            tosses[counter] = 1;
            h++;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Number of tails tosses: " + t);
    System.out.println("Number of heads tosses: " + h);
}
}
```

Here's my question regarding my work.

#### Why doesn't the total number of `tails` and `heads` count doesn't add up to `100`?

Thank you guys for correcting my errors! I decided to just edit my for loop.

```
    for(int counter = 0; counter != tosses.length; counter++)
    {
        if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tosses[counter] = 0;
            t++;
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            tosses[counter] = 1;
            h++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need something like the first half of your question... And what does the total number of tails and heads add up to if not 100? Have you done any debugging work of your own?

Comment: Why you create the array?

Answer (score 4):

you must only call coinToss() once!

```
int value = firstCoin.coinToss();
    if(value  == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                tosses[counter] = 0;
                t++;
            } else if(value  == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                tosses[counter] = 1;
                h++;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

`coinToss()` will generate a random number, which means it could return a different result every time it's called.  So this code doesn't do what you think it will do:

```
    if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 0)
        // code
    {
    } else if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 1)
        // code
    {
    }
```

The first `if` calls `coinToss`, which returns either 0 or 1.  Suppose it returns 1.  Then the `if` fails, so you get down to the `else if`.  Now it has to evaluate this:

```
    } else if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 1)
```

Do you think this will always be `true` because the `coinToss` already returned 1?  No, because **this calls `coinToss` again**.  And the new `coinToss` may return 0, since it's random.  That's why things don't add up.

In this case, you can just say `else` without the second `if`.  But in general, in a case like this, you should declare a new variable to save the result of `coinToss` or whatever other function you're calling, so that you can make sure you only call it once when you only want to call it once.

Answer (score 2):

## Logic Error:

### This makes no logical sense:

Given that `.coinToss()` generates a new number every time it is called.

```
if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 0) // can return 0 or 1
{
   // whatever      
} 
else if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 1) // can return 0 or 1 ( a different result than the if branch )
{
   // whatever
}
```

### it is functionally equivilent as:

This isn't doing what you intended it to do.

```
if((int)(Math.random() *2) == 0)
{
   // whatever      
} else if((int)(Math.random() *2) == 1)
{
   // whatever
}
```

There is a case where the `if` doesn't match and the `else` doesn't match, nothing gets done.

### It should be:

```
final int toss = first.Coin.coinToss();
if(toss == 0)
{
   // whatever      
} 
else if(toss == 1)
{
   // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling coinToss method on firstCoin object twice. When the code checks the if and else if statements, the if and else if statements will execute coinToss methods separately.

For example, you could have gotten a value of 1 for the first if statement, but when you call it again on the else if statement, you could get a value of 0.

Try this:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter != tosses.length; counter++)
    {

        int coinTossed = firstCoin.coinToss();

        if(coinTossed == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tosses[counter] = 0;
            t++;
        } else if(coinTossed == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            tosses[counter] = 1;
            h++;
        }
    }
```

The heads and tails count wouldn't add up to 100 because there might have been an instance when both if statements did not execute! Thus, nothing was added to neither t or h.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 0) {
     System.out.println("Tails");
     tosses[counter] = 0;
     t++;
} else if(firstCoin.coinToss() == 1) {
     System.out.println("Heads");
     tosses[counter] = 1;
     h++;
}
```

The problem is here. When you do `firstCoin.coinToss() == 0` and `firstCoin.coinToss() == 1`, these are two separate instances of coin tosses, and there is (on average) a 25% chance you fail to increment either t or h (if you toss 1 then 0)